Does shi 是 have multiple meanings between copula and cleft?
I'm very much a beginner here learning Chinese and am likely to use the wrong grammatical terminology.
I know that you can use 是 to equate a subject to a subject complement (e.g. he is a student). But I've the usage of 是 ... 的 show up in order to emphasize a detail or ask a question with emphasis on a detail.
My question is, does 是 roughly mean "to be"/"is" and if it does, how do I make sense of that with 是 ... 的 constructions when translating it to English. It feels like 是 in 是 ... 的 deserves a different meaning here. If there's some history I'm missing here on the development of 是, I'd love to know that as well!

Are you sure about the "meaning" of "to be / is" first? As a copula, aka joiner, even the confounded Western linguists will affirm, in such usage "to be / is " have no meaning. 是的, 没问题. Can you tell me please, what "be" "means"?

Please provide examples of sentences in "是 ... 的" construction. Note that "是的" is the simple expression of "Yes" without a word or words in between. But I don't think that is your question.

My working theory that I used to explain 是 to myself is that the original/root meaning is "is true" or "is the case". Other verbs which mean "to be" can have a different derivation, e.g. 系 (“can be categorised as") or 为 ("acts as").

@河南宝宝 I like that line of reasoning!

@edaniels full disclosure it's just what seemed to make sense to me at the time, no guarantee that it is academically rigorous

refer to this answer here about the usage of 的 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/53539/use-of-final-%e7%9a%84-de-with-the-verb-%e6%9c%83-%e4%bc%9a-hu%c3%ac?rq=1 .

I'm Chinese. What is mean of cleft? I can understand copula, but I can't understand cleft in your problem.

As a native speaker, I think my answer could be referenced.
In most cases, 是 represents a positive feeling, like "is" or "yes".
For example, in 是...的(when ... is an adjective), it just means "is," but when ... is a noun, it means something "belongs" to someone (possessive), and 是的 means "yes" in a more confident way than 是.
It could also be a last name according to the dictionary.
In original Chinese, it's more difficult to understand (even native speakers struggle to understand).
for more information, you can look at https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=8779&la=0&powerMode=0

I think you can translate is(or am) to 是, but may be to be can't(or most of the time) translate as 是.
For example:

I’m disappointed, to be honest. 说实话，我很失望。

or

I’m disappointed, to be honest. 说实话，我是失望的。

Pay attention to the "to be" above. Usually see to be honest as a phrase，翻译为说实话 or 老实说，一般应该很少把to be翻译为是。
通常把is翻译为是，翻译的时候要根据具体的上下文，如果你有例子是最好了。
